# Windows 7 USB power lose after a few seconds / minutes

Tags: windows-7, usb, usb-flash-drive, connection, power

My friend's computer has a problem where the USB ports causes problems with the power of some devices connected to the computer.

The USB mouse has no problems, however the Wireless Adapter looses power after around 20 seconds of use and USB Flash Drives cause the computer to either freeze, lose power (and become unresponsive) or become disconnected (still shown in Device Manager, but not in My Computer) when trying to transfer any type of file to / from the computer.

I have a suspicion it's the Motherboard but could it also be a Software problem? Tried a new case, RAM, CPU and GFX Card which had no effect.

The problem occurs on both the Front USB and Back (Motherboard) USB Ports.

UPDATE: Tried the USB devices with an Ubuntu Live CD and they work fine, could this mean it's a problem with Windows (x64)?

Comment: Did you try a new PSU as well?

Comment: No. The computer is equipped with a 300W PSU, so that should be enough - it's not a high-end PC (3.0Ghz Pentium D, 4GB DDR2 RAM, Geforce 8600gt) I've updated my original question. I think it could be software based problem involving Windows as they work fine on Ubuntu 12.04 Live CD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to disable "Allow this computer to turn off this device to safe power" on both the Wireless adapter and all USB Root Hubs showing in "Device Manager".

Answer (score 0):

The devices working in Ubuntu but not in Windows suggests a software problem, probably a driver problem.  Try reinstalling the drivers on the wireless adapter and see if that helps (and get the most recent drivers from the manufacturer's website).

Comment: What would you suggest about the USB drivers? There are none on the Manufacturers website.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: Go to the Advanced Settings in the Power Options and Change the USB selective suspend setting to 'Disabled'.