# USB device loses power after 20 seconds Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-7, usb, windows-8.1, power-management, wireless-headset

Alright so I recently started using a Tritton Primer Headset, it worked fine for a day but since then the USB powered baseplate receives power for around 20 seconds then it drops to 0ma.

After 20 seconds:
http://prntscr.com/6v9p7d

When first plugged in: 
http://prntscr.com/6v9pm9

I've tried:

- Removing the device from the registry and adding it back.
- Different cables(over 15)
- Plugging it into a different device(it works, on three other PCs)
- Disabled USB selective suspend settings
- I have now also tried a powered USB hub to no avail.

Comment: Did you try connecting it to another port on the same pc? Or using a powered hub between your pc and the baseplate? This seems like a power problem on the port of your pc.

Comment: I've tried all the ports but I haven't tried a powered hub.

Comment: This behavior (works on other PCs but does not work on any port of your PC) may suggest some failed power negotiations - a powered hub may solve the problem, should be worth the try.

Comment: Alright thanks, I'll try get my hands on a powered hub.

Comment: To be sure, when you say "Disabled USB selective suspend settings" did you try the settings mentioned in the answer to this question? http://superuser.com/questions/478360/windows-7-usb-power-lose-after-a-few-seconds-minutes

Comment: I tried all of the solutions in the answer(s) to that question.

Comment: Powered hub had the same result. Any other solutions?

Comment: No more ideas... Please check the event viewer for any related events and add them to your question.